# Execute C# from within the JVM

Tags: c#, java, .net, jvm

I recently learned about [IKVM.net](http://www.ikvm.net/) which is a Java for Mono (.NET). So I am guessing that there could be out there a implementation of CLR on Java. That can be used to run C# functions in Java, (not really those .NET UI stuff) mainly those codes that are logic or algorithm-oriented programs, one good example would be a "parser" for example.

Something that would not just "convert" the code, something that will execute C# function directly to the JVM allowing it to interact with other Java objects perhaps. As I had this experience trying to use C# to Java converters which the result is most like approximation code which is even harder to fix.

Is there any implementation of CLR on top of JVM at this point in time?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: As far as I know the answer is NO. JVM is less modernized compared to .NET CLR, so it is not unexpected to see no CLR on JVM. If you are interested in this area, you can write your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to use [jni4net](http://jni4net.sourceforge.net/) to bridge between Java and C#.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out [Grasshopper](http://dev.mainsoft.com/Default.aspx?tabid=130)? I don't know how good it is, but it was started years ago for that purpose.